# typedef singleton as member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, typedef

Trying to access the member variable s below, results in the following error:

> **error: 'cl::s {aka singleton}' is not a base of 'cl'**

```
class singleton
{

public:
static singleton* getInstance()
{
  static singleton* ptr{nullptr};
  if(nullptr==ptr)
  {
    ptr=new singleton;
  }
  return ptr;
}
private:
  int m_var;
};

class cl
{
public:
   typedef singleton s;

};

int main() 
{
  cl* c;
  c->s::getInstance();
}
```

I wasn't expecting an error of this sort. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be argued that the main thing you're doing wrong is using a singleton in the first place.

Comment: this is a consolidated example. It's not code I wrote, it's code I have to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access type names through an instance.  Write:

```
cl::s::getInstance();
```

C++ is interpreting `c->s::getInstance()` as an attempt to call `s::getInstance` on the object pointed to by `c`.  You can use this syntax when calling overridden (or hidden) member functions on a base class, or disambiguating member functions inherited from multiple base classes:

```
struct A { void foo(); };
struct B: A { void foo(); };
B b;
b.foo();     // calls B::foo
b.A::foo();  // calls A::foo
```

Comment: And even then `cl::s` is not accessible.

Comment: The typedef needs to be moved to public as well to be accessed in this way.

Comment: Not to mention that `i` is undefined, but this is main issue. Rest is kinda trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I had a "#define private public" and forgot to include it. And I forgot to take the .i out. Fixed and Fixed